# How to display data in HIGHCHART from mysql database using datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

have a problem when i choose the start date and end date in datepicker to display the data in highchart, the data in highchart is display alll data..so plaese some body to fix it. thank u

this's my source code

```
<script>
function dialogbx(){

myDialogBox('9');
}window.addEventListener("load",dialogbx);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1; // globally available
 $(document).ready(function() {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
     },   
     title: {
        text: ''
     },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Type Grafik : Column'
     },
     xAxis: {
        categories:  [
        <?php 
            $sql2   = "SELECT * FROM pinjaman WHERE $filterPeriode GROUP   BY tgl_pinjam ";      
            $query2 = mysql_query( $sql2 )  or die(mysql_error());
            while($ret2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ 
                $tahun = $ret2['tgl_pinjam']; ?>
             'Tanggal <?php echo $tahun; ?>',
            <?php } ?>
        ] ,


     },
     yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: 'Jumlah Pinjaman (Rupiah) '
        }
     },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },


series: [


    <?php 
    include('../library/inc.connection.php');
    $query1=mysql_query("select kd_jenis from pinjaman where  $filterPeriode && level ='1' group by kd_jenis");
    while($array1=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){ 
        $kdjenis = $array1['kd_jenis'];


    ?>
    {
        name: '<?php echo $kdjenis; ?>',

        data: [<?php $query3 = mysql_query("select * from pinjaman WHERE $filterPeriode && level ='1' group by tgl_pinjam "); 
                    while($array3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){
                        $query4 = mysql_query("select kd_jenis,SUM(jumlah_pinjam) from pinjaman where kd_jenis='$kdjenis' && 
                                                 $filterPeriode && level ='1' group by kd_jenis "); 
                        while( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $query4 ) ){
                            $jumlah = $data['SUM(jumlah_pinjam)'];                 
                        }
                        echo $jumlah.",";
                    } ?>]

    },
    <?php  } ?>
    ]

      });
      });   
    </script>
```

Comment: I can see you have `xAxis.categories` - what kind of datepicker (?) allows to choose date between "apple" and "orange"? ;) See example with categories [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative). I guess you want to use `xAxis.type="datetime"`. Check out [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type).

Comment: sorry mr pawel to late reply ur message..in my x.categories to display date from database. i guess i have a problem in data series,so how to display data in highchart when i choose start and date date picker thn i click button show,..so far it work but the data in highchart is display same in all date.

Comment: this is my html code                                                                                                                                       <tr>
  <td>From
  <input  class="text1" type="text" value="<?php echo $stardate; ?>"  id="datepicker1" onMouseOver="setdate(1)" name="txtstartdate"/>
  </td>
  <td>End <input    class="text1" type="text" value="<?php echo $enddate; ?>" id="datepicker2" onMouseOver="setdate(2)" name="txtenddate"/></td>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="button black" name="buttonshow" type="submit" value=" show " /></td>

Comment: Well, your HTML code won't help. Have you even read the API links I send you? If you want to use datepicker, then I would resign from categories and use datetime axis. If still prefer categorized axis, then you need to find corresponding category when using datepicker and predict what should happen when user will choose date which doesn't exist in your chart (and probably more issues)..

Comment: hello mr pawel..i already read Api reference but in the Api reference example is working static,how to working with database to display range data using jquery datepicker,sorry i am new with highchart..please help me to out from this problem

Comment: Using datepicker in both scenarios is the same. The difference is that you load data from database (i.e by ajax) and push in series. Other elements are the same.

Comment: yeah mr sebastian, but now i have a problem in series:[] i think with my query,when i choose range selector the data in higchart is display all